# unable to upload image to amazon s3 from froala WSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, image-upload, froala

I am using froala editor which also has image upload to s3, I followed the steps as mentioned in the docs [here](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/sdks/nodejs/image-s3-upload)

CORS configuration on s3 bucket

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
        <CORSRule>
            <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
            <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
            <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
            <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
            <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
            <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
        </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The server side code

```
router.route('/get_signature')
  .get((req, res) => {
    var configs = {
      // The name of your bucket.
      bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,

      // S3 region. If you are using the default us-east-1, it this can be ignored.
      region: 'us-east-1',

      // The folder where to upload the images.
      keyStart: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_PROJECT_NAME + '/' + process.env.AWS_BUCKET_BLOGS,

      // File access.
      acl: 'public-read',

      // AWS keys.
      accessKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    }

    var s3Hash = FroalaEditor.S3.getHash(configs);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(s3Hash) + " :s3Hash");//this holds the s3Hash
    res.send(s3Hash);
  })
```

Get request on my client side

```
$.get('/blog/get_signature', {})
      .done(function (s3Hash) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(s3Hash) + " :s3Hash"); //hold the response
        $('textarea#froala-editor').froalaEditor({
          imageUploadToS3: s3Hash,
          paragraphFormat: {
            h3: "Blog Title",
            h4: "Abstract",
            body: "Body"
          },
        })
        .on('froalaEditor.contentChanged', function (e, editor) {
            $('#preview').html(editor.html.get());
          })

         .on('froalaEditor.image.uploadedToS3', function (e, editor, link, key, response) {
            // Image was uploaded to the server.
            console.log("Image uploaded to s3 " + JSON.stringify(response));
          })
      })
```

I tried to follow the docs to perfection but the image is still not getting uploaded to s3. I don't know where I might be going wrong, I have researched and researched but did not find a proper solution to this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Any number of things could be going wrong. Also make sure that you have a CORS policy set correctly on the s3 bucket. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: @ChrisThompson I have added CORS policy on the s3 bucket, please check the edit to my question. I am not getting any errors, its just not uploading the image to the s3 bucket.

Comment: console.log("Image uploaded to s3 " + JSON.stringify(response)); --> thiis doesn't give anything ?

Comment: @JamesDean no it doesn't give anything. The event itself isn't invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to the question I posted above, posting an answer as it might be helpful for anyone who stumbles across this problem.

I fixed the upload issue by adding the option `imageUploadUrl : false` inside the initialisation of the editor.